# Parse XML data file into HTML table using XSLT and XPath

Tags: html, xml, xslt, xpath

I'm trying to take an XML file that a user will save into a folder, and create an HTML page that will parse certain nodes in that XML and display it in a HTML table. Similar to the W3Schools example at this page :-
https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryxslt.asp?xmlfile=cdcatalog&xsltfile=cdcatalog

This example is easy for me to follow, and will allow me (or a business analyst) to create clone pages with different nodes parsing into it - however; what I cannot see is how the files link together and end up displaying in the HTML.

I would prefer NOT to have the user have to open the HTML page, if possible and modify any section having the XML as an internally referenced variable.

Update: further down on the W3Schools site, I found this page: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_client.asp which hints that it will do exactly what I want it to do, however I cannot get this working either.

Comment: Struggling to understand what exactly you're struggling with here? Do you want to place an XML file and an HTML file into a folder and combine them?

Comment: Hi @DanGardner, thanks for your reply. I was hoping to place an XML file in that folder, and have an HTML file that will parse and display it, with minimal editing of the XML file. I'm sure I've done it before, and the links I posted seem to hint that it is possible. I was trying to avoid having to write a program for someone.

Comment: No worries! Okay I understand a bit better now. So you've followed the second example so far, so you have an HTML document with Javascript code in and then also an XML file and an XSLT file to convert it to a table right? Could you post examples of a snippet of XML, your XSLT and the Javascript code you're using.